# How do I pick random unique lines from a text file in shell?

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have a text file with an unknown number of lines.  I need to grab some of those lines at random, but I don't want there to be any risk of repeats.

I tried this:

```
jot -r 3 1 `wc -l<input.txt` | while read n; do
  awk -v n=$n 'NR==n' input.txt
done
```

But this is ugly, and doesn't protect against repeats.

I also tried this:

```
awk -vmax=3 'rand() > 0.5 {print;count++} count>max {exit}' input.txt
```

But that obviously isn't the right approach either, as I'm not guaranteed even to get `max` lines.

I'm stuck.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `jot` is on your system, then I guess you're running FreeBSD or OSX rather than Linux, so you probably don't have tools like `rl` or `sort -R` available.

No worries.  I had to do this a while ago.  Try this instead:

```
$ printf 'one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\n' > input.txt
$ cat rndlines
#!/bin/sh

# default to 3 lines of output
lines="${1:-3}"

# default to "input.txt" as input file
input="${2:-input.txt}"

# First, put a random number at the beginning of each line.
while read line; do
  printf '%8d%s\n' $(jot -r 1 1 99999999) "$line"
done < "$input" |
sort -n |               # Next, sort by the random number.
sed 's/^.\{8\}//' |     # Last, remove the number from the start of each line.
head -n "$lines"        # Show our output

$ ./rndlines input.txt 
two
one
five
$ ./rndlines input.txt 
four
two
three
$
```

Here's a 1-line example that also inserts the random number a little more cleanly using awk:

```
$ printf 'one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\n' | awk 'BEGIN{srand()} {printf("%8d%s\n", rand()*10000000, $0)}' | sort -n | head -n 3 | cut -c9-
```

Note that different versions of `sed` (in FreeBSD and OSX) may require the `-E` option instead of `-r` to handle ERE instead or BRE dialect in the regular expression if you want to use that explictely, though everything I've tested works with escapted bounds in BRE.  (Ancient versions of `sed` (HP/UX, etc) might not support this notation, but you'd only be using those if you already knew how to do this.)

Comment: This looks like it'll work for me without the need to install any extra tools or languages (perl, python, bash).  You're right, I'm running FreeBSD.  Thanks for spelling everything out.  I'll recombine the commands with pipes to make it all more compact.

Comment: cat /path/to/file |awk 'BEGIN { srand() } { print rand() "\t" $0 }' | sort -n | cut -f2- > /path/to/random.file

Comment: @CodeReaper - ya, using awk and cut make things cleaner.  I broke up the steps into separate lines for easier documentation.

Answer (score 7):

This might work for you:

```
shuf -n3 file
```

[shuf](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html#shuf-invocation) is one of GNU coreutils.

Comment: Alas, GNU coreutils are not built in to FreeBSD.

Comment: @ghoti Not only did the OP not mention FreeBSD, but he also did not mention being opposed to installing new software. On OS X these are readily available as `brew install coreutils`.

Comment: @Johann In fact, the OP *did* in fact mention that he's using FreeBSD in multiple comments (on my answer and on Glenn's), and his question mentioned tools that are native to FreeBSD.

Answer (score 5):

If you have Python accessible (change the `10` to what you'd like):

```
python -c 'import random, sys; print("".join(random.sample(sys.stdin.readlines(), 10)).rstrip("\n"))' < input.txt
```

(This will work in Python 2.x and 3.x.)

Also, (again change the `10` to the appropriate value):

```
sort -R input.txt | head -10
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick, at least with `bash` and assuming your environment has the other commands available:

```
cat chk.c | while read x; do
    echo $RANDOM:$x
done | sort -t: -k1 -n | tail -10 | sed 's/^[0-9]*://'
```

It basically outputs your file, placing a random number at the start of each line.

Then it sorts on that number, grabs the last 10 lines, and removes that number from them.

Hence, it gives you ten random lines from the file, with no repeats.

For example, here's a transcript of it running three times with that `chk.c` file:

```
====
pax$ testprog chk.c
} else {
}
newNode->next = NULL;
colm++;

====
pax$ testprog chk.c
}

arg++;
printf (" [%s] n", currNode->value);
free (tempNode->value);

====
pax$ testprog chk.c

char tagBuff[101];
}
return ERR_OTHER;
#define ERR_MEM 1

===
pax$ _
```

Comment: I don't have bash installed, just sh.  I'll try installing it if the other solutions don't work.  Thanks.

Comment: This is more likely to select lines from the end of files, because there can be more than n lines that start with 32767.

Comment: @Lri, no it won't. Random numbers are assigned (pseudo) randomly. It's not more likely that lines will have 32767 than any other number. And speed will only be an issue if the files are massive, in which case I probably wouldn't even _use_ a shell for this.

Comment: Try something like `cat /usr/share/dict/words | while read x; do echo $RANDOM:$x; done | sort -t: -k1 -n | tail -3`.

Comment: @Lri, I get `32693:barfs`, `32664:lurker` and `32687:asbestos`. Is there some other result you're getting that makes you doubt it's working?

Comment: Of course, you're _likely_ to get a different result (as I did when running it a second time). My question is: does the result you get seem somehow non-random?

Comment: My `/usr/share/dict/words` is 235886 lines. There's usually 4 or more lines that start with 32767, but only the last 3 ones get printed. (But I misunderstood what the sort command does earlier, so they're actually the lines sorted last by `sort` and not lines at the end of the file.)

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now but I don't see that as a problem. the words are assigned random keys and you explicitly ask for  three of them, so that's what you get. If you want some other number, or all the words with the 32767 code, use a different value for tail, or a method totally different to tail, like `grep '^32767:'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sort -Ru filename | head -5
```

will ensure no duplicates. Not all implementations of `sort` have the `-R` option.

Comment: `sort -Ru <<< $'1\n1\n2' | head -2` removes duplicate lines, so it never returns 1 and 1. Without `-u` duplicate lines would be sorted together, so it would return either 1 and 1 or 2 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

To get `N` random lines from `FILE` with Perl:

```
perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e 'print shuffle <>' FILE | head -N
```

Comment: Perl can do the job of `head`: `perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e '$n = 3; @foo = shuffle <>; print @foo[0..$n]' FILE`

Comment: Of course, but I believe it's more convenient. I don't mind to mix different tools, sometimes I use filters with awk/sed/perl and unix utilities in one command. Once I even used python :).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer using ruby if you don't want to install anything else:

```
cat filename | ruby -e 'puts ARGF.read.split("\n").uniq.shuffle.join("\n")'
```

for example, given a file (dups.txt) that looks like:

```
1 2
1 3
2
1 2
3
4
1 3
5
6
6
7
```

You might get the following output (or some permutation):

```
cat dups.txt| ruby -e 'puts ARGF.read.split("\n").uniq.shuffle.join("\n")'
4
6
5
1 2
2
3
7
1 3
```

Further example from the comments:

```
printf 'test\ntest1\ntest2\n' | ruby -e 'puts ARGF.read.split("\n").uniq.shuffle.join("\n")'
test1
test
test2
```

Of course if you have a file with repeated lines of test you'll get just one line:

```
printf 'test\ntest\ntest\n' | ruby -e 'puts ARGF.read.split("\n").uniq.shuffle.join("\n")'
test
```

Comment: How does this randomize the output?  Also, if the same content is on multiple lines of the input file, it should be possible for the random output to show that data twice, as I want to select unique *lines*, not unique *content*.

Comment: Sorry I inadvertently left out the shuffle. That uniq is just operating on the array of lines, so you should be getting unique lines not content.

Comment: Thanks, but I think `uniq` is not behaving that way.  If I feed your ruby script the output of `printf 'test\ntest\ntest\n'`, I should still see three lines of `test` as my output.  I only see one.  According to the [ruby doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq), `uniq` returns unique *values*, which is not how I want to process my input data.

Comment: But I thought you wanted uniq lines? If you feed in test\ntest\ntest\n of course you'll end up with one unique line of 'test'. Added to the examples above.

Comment: No, you're confusing "lines" with "content".  If "test" appears on line 1, that's valid for output.  If it also appears on line 2, that is also valid for output.  What I want is to avoid showing line X twice, regardless of whether it's the same content as on line Y.

Answer (score 0):

While I appreciate OP is on FreeBSD, and I'm not sure this would work on their system, but [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell)'s [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) and [`Get-Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-random) might be a useful and clean alternative?

```
Get-Content "path/to/file" | Get-Random
```

You can optionally use `Get-Random`'s `-Count` parameter to retrieve N lines:

```
Get-Content "path/to/file" | Get-Random -Count N
```

PowerShell (5.1) is available on Windows by default, but PowerShell 7.x is available for install on [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows) [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-linux) and [macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-macos)